# troubles modules Django mas os - pycharm

Tags: python, django, macos, operating-system, pycharm

dears.

I'm new in python/django. I just try Install and configure an enviroment from my ubuntu to my mac os. I've installed Python 3.6 , Django 2.0 and i'm using pycharm. When I tried run with "runserver", I got this error:

```
/Users/fabio/Documents/projects/lib/python3.6/site-packages/magic/__pycache__/_cffi__xa0d5132dx54cebdac.c:208:10: fatal error: 'magic.h' file not found
#include <magic.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
/Users/fabio/Documents/projects/lib/python3.6/site-packages/magic/__pycache__/_cffi__xa0d5132dx54cebdac.c:208:10: fatal error: 'magic.h' file not found
#include <magic.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x10ea68268>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 118, in _compile
    extra_postargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 909, in spawn
    spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/spawn.py", line 36, in spawn
    _spawn_posix(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/spawn.py", line 159, in _spawn_posix
    % (cmd, exit_status))
distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fabio/Documents/projects/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cffi/ffiplatform.py", line 55, in _build
    dist.run_command('build_ext')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
    self._build_extensions_serial()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 533, in build_extension
    depends=ext.depends)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
    self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 120, in _compile
    raise CompileError(msg)
distutils.errors.CompileError: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fabio/Documents/projects/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/fabio/Documents/projects/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/fabio/Documents/projects/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/Users/fabio/Documents/projects/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/fabio/Documents/projects/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/fabio/Documents/projects/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/fabio/Documents/projects/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Users/fabio/Documents/projects/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/fabio/Documents/projects/voiservices/source/sambalife/myauth/models.py", line 12, in <module>
    from utils.helper import send_email
  File "/Users/fabio/Documents/projects/voiservices/source/sambalife/utils/helper.py", line 23, in <module>
    from shipment.views import shipment_paypal_notification, shipment_paypal_notification_success
  File "/Users/fabio/Documents/projects/voiservices/source/sambalife/shipment/views.py", line 35, in <module>
    import magic
  File "/Users/fabio/Documents/projects/lib/python3.6/site-packages/magic/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import ffi
  File "/Users/fabio/Documents/projects/lib/python3.6/site-packages/magic/ffi.py", line 27, in <module>
    ext_package="magic")
  File "/Users/fabio/Documents/projects/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 437, in verify
    lib = self.verifier.load_library()
  File "/Users/fabio/Documents/projects/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cffi/verifier.py", line 113, in load_library
    self._compile_module()
  File "/Users/fabio/Documents/projects/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cffi/verifier.py", line 210, in _compile_module
    outputfilename = ffiplatform.compile(tmpdir, self.get_extension())
  File "/Users/fabio/Documents/projects/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cffi/ffiplatform.py", line 29, in compile
    outputfilename = _build(tmpdir, ext, compiler_verbose)
  File "/Users/fabio/Documents/projects/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cffi/ffiplatform.py", line 62, in _build
    raise VerificationError('%s: %s' % (e.__class__.__name__, e))
cffi.ffiplatform.VerificationError: CompileError: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I tried install that peckage, but i got this error interminal:

```
sh-3.2# python3.6 -m pip install magic
Collecting magic
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement magic (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for magic
```

Somebody help me please?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`brew install libmagic` should help.

Comment: I tryed and got it, but, now this erro:  line 11, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'. Itryed install this dependence, but, other error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PIL

Comment: `pip install image`   then

Comment: and `pip install Pillow`

Comment: @FábioMarques: consider accepting the answer if your question was resolved.